# Length of an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

if I have an array of pointers like char **lines, how can i determine its length?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You have to manually keep track of the length of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reliably.

Sometimes, there is a null pointer marking the end - it is one convention sometimes used.  More often, you need to be told the length.

But there is no fool-proof way of determining the length.  You have to know (or be told) the length, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an array of pointers, it's a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data.  If there is no associated count, it could be a NULL terminated list.

```
char** lines = mysteryfunction();
for ( ;*lines;lines++ ) { 
    printf( "%s\n", *list ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Getting the length of a pointer to an array

```
char *array[]={"welcome","to","India"};

length=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Output:

> 3

we can get the length by dividing ***(size of pointer to array by size of single one)***

Because there is no predefined function for getting length of array..

Comment: Read the question. The OP doesn't have an array. He just has a pointer to the first element.